# Disabling particular jenkins job for cloning

Tags: jenkins

We have some jobs which should'nt be duplicated?
Is it possible to disable cloning(copying) of a particular job in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes close in the [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/) is:

|  | Job |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | Create | ... |
| ☐ | ☐ | ☐ |

Comment: I think to disable the cloning, you'd have to disable read on thw source, so probably not practically possible.

Comment: @IanW And another question is who is reading the job's `config.xml` (at cloning or elsewhen): The user that's logged on or the user that runs the Jenkins instance.

Comment: Your Q should be directed to the OP. While the posting lacks sufficient detail, one can assume that the person copying the job has permission to do so now. Unless you remove the read permission from that user, they can effectively replicate, if not via the GUI. Blocking Create "works" as it prevents copying as then NO new job can be created, but that's a sledgehammer. Block Read for the job in question is a scalpel. I believee he's talking about a Jenkins user and not an App or OS Admin .

Comment: User is admin can read the job and few other folks. We have certain config in the job needs to be changed mandatory after cloning the job. If not, this will overwrite previous job config and this causes serious problem for us.  User can read the job and modify, but cannot clone. If that's possible.